# Getting Django models instance field values after changing them

Tags: django, django-models

Let's consider the following:

```
a = Model.objects.get(pk=1)
a.name  # foo
a.name = "bar"
a.name  # bar
```

How can I now get the previous value "foo"?
I don't want to select again or make a copy of a prior changes. Any other ideas? Maybe there is a place where those changes are held.

Comment: As @YujiTomita points out by pretty much entirely ignoring your two stipulations, ;) the two ways you *don't* want to do are the only two ways to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - that's a great point... I didn't notice those two stipulations! Oops...

Answer (score 1):

You can either query the database again (`Model.objects.get(pk=1).name`)

Or you store the state of the model in some attribute.. this is often done to detect changes.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initial = self.__dict__

a = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
a.name = "bar"
a._initial['name'] == "foo"
```